# Sign CPI as both a PDA and signer of TX

Tags: anchor, cpi, signing, multisig

I am writing an anchor program where I want to sign a CPI as both a PDA from my program and the signer of the tx. I expect it would look something like this:

````
CpiContext::new_with_signer(
   program,
   accounts,
   [ctx.accounts.signer, pda_signer_seeds]
)```

How would one do this?
````

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to explicitly pass the non-PDA signer into the `signer_seeds` array. It will be passed through from the the caller automatically as long as `is_signer` is `true` in the corresponding `AccountInfo` in your accounts array.

https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/cpi.html#cpi-with-invoke

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example using the CpiContext::new_with_signer to transfer some tokens from a token vault owned by this program. Inside the seeds I put in the values needed to create the PDA of the vault as described in the Withdraw vault_account seeds.

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Withdraw<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"vault", to.mint.as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub vault_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"vault-access", to.mint.as_ref(), authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump, 
        constraint = vault_access.authority == authority.key()
    )]
    pub vault_access: Account<'info, VaultAccess>,
    #[account(mut, constraint = to.owner == authority.key())]
    pub to: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
}
pub fn withdraw(ctx: Context<Withdraw>, amount: u64, bump: u8) -> Result<()> {
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.vault_account.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.to.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.vault_account.to_account_info(),
        };

        if amount > ctx.accounts.vault_access.amount {
            return Err(ErrorCode::InsufficientFundsInVault.into())
        }

        ctx.accounts.vault_access.amount -= amount;

        token::transfer(
            CpiContext::new_with_signer(
                cpi_program, 
                cpi_accounts,
                &[&[b"vault", ctx.accounts.to.mint.as_ref(), &[bump]]]), 
            amount)?;
        Ok(())
    }
```

Note - with the latest version of anchor you don't need to pass the bump in as a parameter if you don't want to. There are new ways to deal with the bump that can make things a bit easier.